# Using ResNet50 or ResNet34 or AlexNet to build a CNN model

Tags: python, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm wondering which algorithm to use between  ResNet50/ResNet34/AlexNet models in order to build a CNN model to predict the style of an art

Comment: Do you need speed or accuracy? Either way don't use alexNet. Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as your question is just as vague as it gets.

Comment: sorry I need accuracy , I update

Comment: If you need accuracy, then use ResNet50. However it's still difficult to say as to get a satisfying answer you should give a better description of the task at hand, the data that you have and so on.